# Vue How to return value from async/await function in a computed

Tags: vue.js, async-await, promise, vuejs3, state

I have a vue js searchbar when i type in the input bar it needs to show results based on the matching characters

For getting the data I'm using async await function to wait for the api response but it's in computed so it returns a promise so it can't identify it but when i print it shows the correct data but it's not shown in the ui

`

```
<template>
 <li v-for="name in names">
      {{ name }}
    </li>
<template>
<script>
export default{
computed: {
  async filteredNames() {
return await apicall();
  }
}}</script>
```

Comment: There's no reason to use a computed in this case since there's nothing to compute from.  You can call the API once on mounted and assign the response to a local property. If there is any condition that will require refreshing the API data (I suspect a filter text), use a watcher on that variable to call the API again.

Comment: Hi @Igor Moraru yes I have a filtertext so i can filter search results can u pls provide a eg code on how to that. It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Does the filtering happening on the server or are you filtering the results in the component?

Comment: I'm filtering it in the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the filtering is happening in the component, you don't need to call the API every time when you are filtering the results. Save the API data in the component, and return the filtered results from local data:

```
<template>
 <input v-model="filterText">
 <li v-for="name in filteredItems">
    {{ name }}
 </li>
<template>

<script>
  export default{
    data(){
      return {
        allItems: [],
        filterText: ""
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filteredItems() {
          return this.allItems.filter(item => item.includes(this.filterText))
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      callApi().then(res => {
          this.allItems = res.data
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks Igor Moraru .Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

For api call you can use created..

```html
<template>
 <li v-for="name in filteredNames">
      {{ name }}
    </li>
<template>
<script>
export default{
data: {
  return {
    allData: []
    searchKey: null
  }
}
computed: {
  filteredNames() {
    return this.allData.filter(data => data.name === searchKey)
  }
  
  created () {
    getAllNames()
  }
  
  method: {
    getAllNames async() {
      const res = await apiCall()
      this.allData = res.json()
    }
  }
}}</script>
```